# Vectors/matrices: How to show that $(v-w)(v-w)^t v = \frac{1}{2}\lVert v-w\rVert^2 (v-w)\quad$ (vector notation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Given the following details:

$v \neq w$ two vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lVert v\rVert = \lVert w\rVert$. Let $u = \frac{1}{\lVert v-w\rVert}(v-w)$ and $H = I - 2uu^t$. Suppose $x$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$,

$$x = Hx = x - 2uu^tx.$$

Then $u^t x = 0$, $\{ x : u^t x = 0\} = \operatorname{Span} (u)^\perp$. Further $Hv = w$ and $Hw = v$,

$$v^t v = w^tw \implies (v-w)^tv = \frac{1}{2}\lVert v-w\rVert^2,$$

thus

$$Hv = v - \frac{2}{\lVert v-w\rVert^2}(v-w)(v-w)^tv = v - \frac{2\frac{1}{2}\lVert v-w\rVert^2}{\lVert v-w\rVert^2}(v-w) = w.$$

How is the relation below found, is Cauchy-Schwarz and the triangle inequality involved here, or something much simpler? What exactly are the steps in between?:

$$(v-w)(v-w)^tv = \frac{1}{2}\lVert v-w\rVert^2(v-w).$$

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are $1 \times n$ vectors, then$xy^t = (x,y)$, the dot product of $x$ and $y$. So $xx^t = \|x\|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from $v^tv=w^tw$. Then
$$\begin{align}||v-w||^2&=(v-w)^t(v-w)\\&=v^tv-v^tw-w^tv+w^tw\\&\stackrel{(1)}=2v^tv-2w^tv\\&=2(v-w)^tv\end{align}$$
In step (1) we use $v^tv=w^tw$ and also the fact that $v^tw$ is a scalar (so that $v^tw=w^tv$). Finally, everything in the above chain of equations is a scalar so we can multiply it on the left or on the right of $(v-w)$.

Comment: cool, the clue is that the 2.nd equality you mention is equal because they're scalars, elegant solution, thx

Comment: hmm, maybe it was clear at the time, but now looking over this I just realized something that I don't get to add up in my head. Our starting point is:
$(v-w)(v-w)^t$ which can't be equal to $(v-w)^t(v-w)$ because v and w are vectors. Lets say y = w-v (cause 1 vector minus another equals a vector). So we get $(v-w)(v-w)^t = yy^t$ and  $(v-w)^t(v-w) = y^ty$. By def. we know that $yy^t$ returns a matrix while $y^ty$ returns a scalar/the norm. So aren't we really basically claiming that $(v-w)(v-w)^t = (v-w)^t(v-w)$ above which I just said must be impossible? What am I missing?

Comment: Or in other words, whats the step right after: $(v-w)(v-w)^t$?

Comment: Your point that $(v-w)(v-w)^t$ is not equal to $(v-w)^t(v-w)$ is valid, but doesn't harm the argument. The argument goes: $(v-w)(v-w)^tv=(v-w)[(v-w)^tv]=(v-w)[\frac12||v-w||^2] = [\frac12||v-w||^2](v-w)$. The quantity in brackets is scalar, so you can trade places in the scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thx. Yes, definitely see that now, the scalar can be moved anywhere, and the norm is a scalar. Nice trick!